# Open TFS Work Item Attachment in Image Viewer not Web Browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, workitem

Is there a way to open an attachment for a TFS work item by double clicking on it (or rather just opening it from the IDE) in your computer's default image viewer, rather than opening it in a web browser? I'd love to be able to change this setting (if it is a setting).

Edit: after reviewing Kate Gregory's response, I looked into this option and realized that the trouble is that VS is launching a url (a handler file to respond with the attachment), which results in the default web browser being launched. A potential work around i'm considering is writing a custom mapper for all web based calls (as in, when going to start->run and enter a URL) that the mapper would determine what kind of call it is (TFS, etc) and use an appropriate program, based on the MIME type responded with, with a second phase to be incorporate this as a VS add-in.

Comment: There's a Stack Exchange proposal for a Visual Studio ALM Q&A site that you can help to go live: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15894

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you gotten around to write this mapper and VS add-in? I would love to use it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure VS just uses your default program. Word for .doc files, IE for .htm files, and (in your case I bet) IE for .jpg files. Try changing the default program you're using in Windows and see what happens.

Comment: You're right, trick is the image is actually a TFS URL, which returns an image

Answer (score 1):

All files saved in TFS are saved in a path that starts with the following address:

http ://{YourServerName}TFS01:8080/tfs/.../.../...&FileName={YourFileName}.{YourExt}

This means that all files are opened using the default program defined for HTTP protocol, regardless of the extension for your file.
You can probably change the default program for your HTTP protocol (if you have permissions, and usually you wouldn't) but this would also affect opening any regular web page or URL, which is probably not recommended.

I still haven't found a workaround this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of preview function in VST/Team Explorer would be nice. Then, only a minor of attachments must be opened in the browser.
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6224713-preview-attachments-in-team-explorer