# Opening WI attachment without downloading it first in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Does anyone know how I can open an attachment from a work item without having to download it first?

When I double click the attachment, the explorer is opened and the file is downloaded and only then I can open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't as far as I'm aware as the IDE will get the attachment from the TFS server using a web service and thus opens a browser and uses IE for this.

Please see this related item for more info: [Open TFS Work Item Attachment in Image Viewer not Web Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953455/open-tfs-work-item-attachment-in-image-viewer-not-web-browser)